# Redis flush when connection ends

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I'm developing a clustered NodeJS application that uses a single Redis server to share data with multiple application instances.

The problem is when 1 of the application instances (using NodeJS) crash or reload, the keys are retained in Redis. I need a strategy to handle application an application crash/disconnection without duplicating data.

Is there a way to flush the Redis cache when the connection is lost/ended?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a TTL to all your keys and update the TTL before the keys expire. If one of your applications goes down, it won't renew its keys and after the TTL, they'll be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear what you mean by connection ending, but to clear your Redis instance, go into your terminal and type `node` to open the `node` repl and set up your Redis client like so:

`> const redis = require('redis');`

`> const redisUrl = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379';`

`> const client = redis.createClient(redisUrl);`

`> client.flushall()`